# Material design layout grid more than 12 colum

Tags: html, razor, material-design, material-components

I'm trying to create a grid to which has one column per day of the month.
So I need up to 32 columns in a single row (1st label + days of the month)

I'm using a ***for*** in order to add divs dynamically.

```
<section>
    <div class="mdc-layout-grid">
        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__inner">
            @{
                <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-1">
                    Days:
                </div>
                for (var i = 1; i <= Model.TotalDays; i++)
                {
                    <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-1">@Model.GetDateStringFromDay(i)</div>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This gives me 12 values per row, as MDC is 12 column based. 
I tried to create nested divs, but it ended up adding new lines for every new level.

Is there a way to do it? Using nested columns or overriding somehow the default MDC behaviour to allow more columns in a single row?

Comment: I tried to define the SASS variable `$mdc-layout-grid-columns` for 24 columns before the `@material/layout-grid` import, but it had no effect. I may have misunderstood something, but [I raised a bug anyway](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/6896).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sass, it's possible to override the number of columns on Layout Grid with Sass variables:

```
$mdc-layout-grid-columns: (
  desktop: 12,
  tablet: 8,
  phone: 4
);
```

But this will be applied to all MDC-Web Layout Grids in your markup.

Comment: Yes, this would mess up everything else. Unfortunately, I need something to be applied just to this grid

Answer (score 0):

Try using nested grids for this.
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-layout-grid#nested-grid

Create 4 equally divided cells in the layout grid. use cell-3 for this. 3 X 4 = 12

Within each of these cells, create a nested mdc-layout-grid__inner with 8 cells each of cell-1. The end result would be 8 x 4 = 32 cells.